# error in my SharedPreferences project

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am new android developer.& i am learning by developer.android.com
when i run a project about SharedPreferences.my app close with this error "the application has stopped unexpectedly.please try again"

in my project there is a edittext control.user write something on it & press save button & close the app.when user open it again there is that text in edittext.

this is my code:

```
SharedPreferences infor = getSharedPreferences( "information", 0 );
txtNumber.setText( infor.getInt( "number", 032 ) );

btnSave.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SharedPreferences infor = getSharedPreferences( "information", 0 );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = infor.edit();
        editor.putInt( "number", Integer.parseInt( txtNumber.getText().toString() ) );
        editor.commit();

    }
} );
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Please post stack trace

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of your crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change here from

```
txtNumber.setText(infor.getInt("number", 032));
```

to

```
txtNumber.setText(infor.getInt("number", 032)+"");
```

OR

```
int my = infor.getInt("number", 032);
txtNumber.setText(my+"");
```

This gives you as a String. And if you want convert int to String using String class then you can use this way.

```
int my = infor.getInt("number", 032);
String myNumber = String.valueOf(my);
txtNumber.setText(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the int as your text, make it a String first.

```
txtNumber.setText(String.valueOf(infor.getInt("number", 032)));
```